# How to create a batch file to save as date

Tags: batch

I have created a batch file which runs on task scheduler for Sage VIP payroll system. The problem I am getting is the date date returns the word `date.zip`, and not the actual date.

Code:

```
V:
@ECHO OFF
set ldt=%date%
pkzipc -add B:\VIP_Backup_IT\ldt *.pay *.vix
echo ldt
pause
exit
```

I get `ldt.zip` and not the date

Comment: Unless you have mistyped, `echo ldt` will display `ldt`. To display the variable contents you need `echo %ldt%`, though, unless you need `ldt` elsewhere or the `pkzipc` command will run through midnight, it is simpler to forget `ldt` and just use `echo %date%`.

Comment: I thought your second use of `ldt` was intended as a literal file-name. If you want to use `%ldt%` ar the file name, see both Techie007 and Paul's answers, though the latter is more complicated than it needs to be (see my comment below it).

Answer (score 0):

Like `%date%`, to reference variables, you need to wrap their name in percentage signs:

```
V:
@ECHO OFF
set ldt=%date%
pkzipc -add B:\VIP_Backup_IT\%ldt% *.pay *.vix
echo %ldt%
pause
exit
```

Note: depending on your regional settings, your Date format *may* produce a string that is invalid as a file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create or rename a file or directory with Date as name without parsing and removing the slash symbol `/`

Here is one way to get date and parsing it.

```dos
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

echo %YYYY%%MM%%DD%-%HH%%Min%
pkzipc -add B:\VIP_Backup_IT\%YYYY%%MM%%DD%-%HH%%Min% *.pay *.vix

pause
exit
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated - the same result will be achieved with `for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do ltd=%%c%%b%%a`.

Comment: Note that if `/` is not included in the regional date string, then `%ldt%` will contain the same as `%date%`, eg `2015-09-23`.

Comment: @AFH I found a simpler way to cover any [eventuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) that a shorter stuff but raise [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us/203116#203116).